# MVC 5.0 Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a On-line food order site using the MVC Music store model.  There are few enhancement from the original music store, but I'm having an issue which I have no place to look for solution.

My Shopping cart page throws the following error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
The reason for this error is : my Food object is null (this is similar to Album class).

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
        {
            <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
                <td data-th="Product">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Product/Product64x64_" + @item.FoodId.ToString() + ".png")' />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h4 class="nomargin">@item.Food.descr_short.ToUpper()</h4>
                            <p>@Html.ActionLink(item.Food.descr_short, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.FoodId }, null)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Can you include your two models?

Comment: Then make sure you are loading the Food property to some NON NULL value in your action method !

Comment: posted my food and cart model

Comment: Your property descr_short is Null or Empty

Comment: it has value, I see that in the addtoCart Method

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public int food_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Short Desc")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A short description is required")]
    public string descr_short { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    [StringLength(5000)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Food Description is required")]
    public string descr { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ingredient")]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string ingredient { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Unit Size")]
    public int size_unit { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Units Per Meal")]
    public int units_per_meal { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Calories")]
    public int calories { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Available From")]
    public DateTime available_from { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Discontinued?")]
    public bool discontinued { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Discontinued Date")]
    public DateTime? discontinued_dt { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Price")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    [UIHint("Currency")]
    public Decimal price { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Vegetarian?")]
    public bool veg { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Days Available")]
    public string daysAvailable { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


}
 public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true, ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be between 0 and 100")]
    [DisplayName("Quantity")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual Food Food { get; set; }
}
```